# JavaFX - Edit tree view node text by button

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, scenebuilder, treeviewitem

I have a form with a treeview and I want to change the text of the selected item by pressing a button. I can not find how to implement this by pressing a button. I found how to do this by double clicking on a cell, but I cannot understand through the button. Maybe someone knows how to implement this or throw off the link.

I will be very grateful.

Comment: A button outside of the `TreeView` or a button that is part of the cell?

Comment: @fabian Button is not part of the cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the selection model to get the selected `TreeItem` and change it's `value` property.

#### Example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>();
    
    // create data
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");
    
    TreeItem<String> child1 = new TreeItem<>("child1");
    TreeItem<String> child2 = new TreeItem<>("child2");
    root.getChildren().addAll(child1, child2);
    
    child1.getChildren().addAll(
            new TreeItem<>("child1-1"),
            new TreeItem<>("child1-2"));
    
    child2.getChildren().addAll(
            new TreeItem<>("child2-1"),
            new TreeItem<>("child2-2"));
    
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    
    Button button = new Button("Change");
    button.disableProperty().bind(treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    
    button.setOnAction(evt -> {
        // set text of selected item to TextField text
        TreeItem<String> item = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        String text = textField.getText();
        item.setValue(text);
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(treeView, textField, button));
    
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```